# Chromecast v3: Mini Controller showing progressbar instead of Play/Pause button

Tags: android, chromecast, google-cast

I am using below way to integrate **mini_controller** in my chromecast app. However, I always seeing progressbar instead of pause/play button in mini controller.

```
<fragment
        android:id="@+id/cast_mini_controller"
        class="com.google.android.gms.cast.framework.media.widget.MiniControllerFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:castControlButtons="@array/cast_mini_controller_control_buttons"
        app:castProgressBarColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:castShowImageThumbnail="true" />
```

Can anybody please suggest what can be the issue it might be?

I tried various articles and none of them able to resolve this issue. All is working fine except the fact that I can not pause the chromecast video through mini controller inside my app as its showing progressbar always.

**Note:** My application is using queuing mechanism in order to load the chunk of videos at once.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are specifying the correct set of buttons for the fragment:

```
<array name="cast_mini_controller_control_buttons">
    <item>@id/cast_button_type_rewind_30_seconds</item>
    <item>@id/cast_button_type_play_pause_toggle</item>
    <item>@id/cast_button_type_forward_30_seconds</item>
</array>
```

Comment: I have done the same exact way but its not working for me.

Comment: You can file a bug: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:190205%20status:open&s=modified_time:desc

Answer (score 0):

I know it's old, but... I've had a similar problem, - always is showing only 2 instead of 3 buttons. My solution is  'app:castShowImageThumbnail="false"'. After that, 3rd button appears.

https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/android_sender/customize_ui#choose_buttons

"Note: If app:castShowImageThumbnail="false", the album art will be hidden and slots 1, 2, and 3 will be available for control buttons. Otherwise, since the album art will be shown in slot 1, you can provide an empty button for slot 1 and control buttons for slots 2 and 3."